# Check if secret file exist

Tags: ios, xamarin, azure-devops

I have situation where I need to install the correct provisioning profile for my azure pipeline build. I have a lot of apps being built. Half of the apps use the same profile and cert for ad-hoc builds and the other half have distinct profile and certs for each app. I have all the certs/profiles uploaded into secrets in Azure Pipelines, named based on the app. On our previous build server, we had them all installed, so not an issue. Now I need to know which one to install.

I would ideally look to see if the profile and cert exist in the secret library. If it doesn't exist, then run the "common" cert/profile install task. If the app named files do exist, then call the correct task to install it. How can I check if a secret file exist in azure pipelines?

I have seen the code for how to check if a file exist in your repo, but not sure how I could convert that check a secret.

Comment: Hi , do you use [Uploading Data to a Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-storage#uploading-data-to-a-container) to storage the file ?

Answer (score 0):

As I remember when I have tested usage of Download Secure File task(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops), it will always success even if the file does not exist in secret library. Then you can use Powershell to check if file with given name has been downloaded (therefore exists) in agent directory. Then depending on it try to set variable isSecretFileDownloaded that will be used to change order of next steps.

Comment: in build pipelines you can use condition for job.

- job: InstallCommonCertificates
condition: eq(variables['isSecretFileDownloaded '], 'false'))